# The server unable to resolve the link MVC application

Tags: kendo-ui

I am currently working on a kendo ui tab. It contains tab1,tab2,tab3.

The first tab has the kendo ui grid which worked fine. What I am trying to do is when a user selects a record on tab 1, tab 2 , or tab 3 it will be enabled with data populated from controller.

here is the code:

```
function onChange() {

        var grid = $("#product").data("kendoGrid"); ;
        var selected = grid.select();
        if (selected.length) {
            var data = grid.dataItem(selected);
            var trn= data.TRN;


            $($('#tabstrip').find('a.k-link')[3]).data('contentUrl', 'TestPlan?TRN=' + hrn);
            $($('#tabstrip').find('a.k-link')[2]).data('contentUrl', 'Summary?TRN=' + hrn);
            var ts = $('#tabstrip').data("kendoTabStrip");

            ts.reload(ts.tabGroup.children("li")[3]);
            ts.reload(ts.tabGroup.children("li")[2]);
            ts.enable(ts.tabGroup.children("li")[3]);
            ts.enable(ts.tabGroup.children("li")[2]);
        }
    }
```

Testing:
If I use Chrome to inspect the error that they could not find the link of tab 2 and tab 3

So I suspect that my url content not format properly because it works in the local environment but not in the server

So how I could modify the following link using URL.content?

```
$($('#tabstrip').find('a.k-link')[3]).data('contentUrl', 'TestPlan?TRN=' + trn);
            $($('#tabstrip').find('a.k-link')[2]).data('contentUrl', 'Summary?TRN=' + trn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it:

```
 $($('#tabstrip').find('a.k-link')[1]).data('contentUrl', '@(Url.Content("~/TestPlan?TRN="))' + trn);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this syntax : '/TestPlan?TRN='